# Having trouble referring to another component within a component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I'm trying to change the float on a div based on the order it shows up on the page – e.g. odd float left, even float right – but nothing is happening when I refer to the component within an existing component.

This is built in reactjs using gatsbyjs and styles-components.

I can get the &:nth-of-type(even) to work if I do something like:

```
${Image}:before {
    background: red;
}
```

But without ':before' nothing happens. At least nothing that I can tell.

More specifically – and perhaps there's a better way to do this – what I'm trying to do is for even articles in the BlogList, the Image floats right. The odd articles float left. I've simplified my code since y'all don't need to see background colors etc.

```
const Wrapper = style.article`
    &:nth-of-type(even) {
        ${Image} {
            float: right;
        }
    }
`;

const Image = style.div`
    float: left;
`;

const Info = style.div`
    float: right;
`;

const BlogList = ({ title, cover, excerpt }) => (
    <Wrapper>
        <Image>
            <Img fluid={cover} />
        </Image>
        <Info>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <p>{excerpt}</p>
        </Info>
    </Wrapper>
);
```

In theory, by the way I read this, I should get the  in event  to float left. But I'm not. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why you have the equal sign between the `const` keyword and the name of your variable?

Comment: That's me typing too fast. There's not an equal sign there.

Comment: Maybe you need to make `Info` float left as well

Comment: If I apply floats only within `Wrapper` like the following:
`
&:nth-of-type(odd) {
    ${Image} {
      float: right;
    }
    ${Info} {
      float: left;
    }
  }
  &:nth-of-type(even) {
    ${Image} {
      float: left;
    }
    ${Info} {
      float: right;
    }
  }
`

It... still doesn't work. Nothing floats now. I'm convinced I'm missing _something_ between the ${component} and the opening curly bracket but nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out. Turns out I was referring to the components backwards. While I am sure there is a cleaner answer, the following is what worked for me:

```
const Wrapper = styled.article`
`;

const Image = styled.div`
    ${Wrapper}:nth-of-type(odd) & {
        float: left;
    }
    ${Wrapper}:nth-of-type(even) & {
        float: right;
    }
`;

const Info = styled.div`
    ${Wrapper}:nth-of-type(odd) & {
        float: right;
    }
    ${Wrapper}:nth-of-type(even) & {
        float: left;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `Image` and `Info` before `Wrapper` if you're referring to them in `Wrapper`.

```
const Image = style.div`
    float: left;
`;

const Info = style.div`
    float: right;
`;

const Wrapper = styled.article`
  ${Info} { ... }
  ${Image} { ... }
`
```

Otherwise, `styled-component`'d have no idea what those other components are. I'm surprised that it didn't throw an error though.